# Running a Selenium Grid 2 with 200 nodes. How can I increase the Jetty threads?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I am currently running a Selenium Grid 2 with more than 50 nodes registered .
After some time the hub becomes unresponsive and has a very hard time to serve the back and forth communication (http requests) with the nodes.
I read [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) this :

> Relly large (>50 node) Hub installations may need to increase the
>   jetty threads by setting -DPOOL_MAX=512 (or larger) on the java
>   command line.

So my question is, how can I increase the Jetty threads and from where?

Answer (score 3):

Posting here for folks who are looking to scale their Selenium Grid.

DPOOL_MAX is no longer valid and the [documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) needs to be updated. Not sure when that parameter was last used by selenium-server-standalone.jar. You would have to set jettyThreads or jettyMaxThreads for the new value to be picked up.

For example -

`java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -jettyThreads 512`

If unspecified the Jetty default value 200 will be used.

> -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
>           : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or
>          negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.

You can learn about other options by passing in the help option -

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -help`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by running the hub command as below:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role hub -DPOOL_MAX=512
```

-DPOOL_MAX will be set as a env variable for the JVM.

Comment: Hello AJ, I did it but I dont think that it made any difference...I am trying to load test an app  with the Grid but eventually it seems that it is not possible in such a scale.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I run multiple grids which have more than 50 nodes under it. All of the runs without any issues. I do have to restart the grid once in 2 or 3 days. But other than that I don't have any issue. What version of selenium are you using? And which browser are you running the test on?